# {{#each}} handlebars block not being accessed

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm having a problem with a #each loop in a handlebars file. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the syntax in the handlebars file or the JSON object. I've searched online but can't find a solution. Any help appreciated!

**main.handlebars**

```
{{#with content}}

{{!-- questions --}}
<form action='/result' method="get">

    {{#each questions}}
        <p>{{q}}</p><br>
        *... irrelevant code ...*
    {{/each}}

    <input type="submit" value="Get Result">

</form>

{{/with}}
```

**interface.js**

```
/*
    SETUP
 */
// Express
var express = require('express');            // We are using the express library for the web server
const { engine } = require(
    'express-handlebars');                   // Loads handlebars module
var app     = express();                     // We need to instantiate an express object to interact with the server in our code
PORT        = 8315;                          // Set a port number at the top so it's easy to change in the future


app.engine('handlebars', engine());          // Sets handlebars configurations
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');        // Sets to use handlebars engine
app.set("views", "./views");
app.use(express.static('public'));           // Needed to import a css file

/* 
    QUIZ CONTENT
*/
quizContent = () => {
    return {
        title: "What Type of Cookie Are You?",
        description: "Take this fun and easy quiz to find out what kind of cookie you are! Just answer each question, then select Get Result at the bottom of the page",
        questions: [
            {
            q: "Pick a color",
            a1: "Blue", 
            a2: "Red",
            a3: "Green",
            a4: "Purple"
            },
           *... irrelevant content ...*
    }   
    
}
/*
    MAIN PAGE
*/
app.get('/', function(req, res)
    {

        res.render('main', {layout: 'index', content: quizContent()});
                
    });
```

**web page**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC2dB.png)

Comment: What is `content`? I don't see it in what is returned by `quizContent`.

Comment: quizContent returns a JSON object with some quiz content in it. It's shown in the interface.js file

Comment: Oops. I didn't see `content` in the `res.render` call. Moving on: I don't see anything wrong with the template you have shared. I have copied it into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/y5ku3jvr/) and it works just fine. I would start my debugging by logging the value of `questions` from within the `#with content` block, as in: `{{log questions}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is mostly solved.

I ended up defining a variable to contain the quiz content and then returned that variable in quizContent() instead of just directly returning the content. Now everything except a1 through a4 for the last question (pick a pet) show up.

```
/* 
    QUIZ CONTENT
*/
quizContent = () => {

    var jsonQuiz = {
        title: "What Type of Cookie Are You?",
        description: "Take this fun and easy quiz to find out what kind of cookie you are! Just answer each question, then select Get Result at the bottom of the page",
        questions: [
            {
            q: "Pick a color",
            a1: "Blue", 
            a2: "Red",
            a3: "Green",
            a4: "Purple"
            },
            {
            q: "Pick a place to vacation",
            a1: "Mountains",
            a2: "Ocean",
            a3: "City",
            a4: "Forest"
            },
            {
            q: "Pick an occupation",
            a1: "Doctor",
            a2: "Accountant",
            a3: "Veterinarian",
            a4: "Firefighter"
            },
            {
            q: "Pick a late night snack",
            a1: "Popcorn",
            a2: "Chips",
            a3: "Pizza",
            a4: "Ice Cream"
            },
            {
            q: "Pick a pet",
            a1: "Dog",
            a2: "Cat",
            a3: "Hampster",
            a4: "Lizzard"
            }
        ],
        
        Results: {
            r1: "Chocolate Chip",
            r2: "Oatmeal Rasin",
            r3: "Peanut Butter",
            r4: "Snickerdoodle"
        } 
    };
    return jsonQuiz;
    
}
```

[image of web page not showing options for "pick a pet"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Snig.png)